# Scale up Images in Different Resolutions XML

Tags: android-layout, imageview, screen-resolution

I'm trying to maintain aspect ratio on all resolution/densities. For this I create an image of 1080x1080 and scale down on small screens.

The problem is in larger screen resolutions than 1080 like some tablets (2560x1600) the image not scale up.

Device with correct size:

[image]

Device with a incorrect size (the resolution of screen is larger than image)

[image]

This is the code for xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@color/blancoo">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/t4"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** If I change the `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` the image scale up correctly but the borders of the image not be the borders of the real image. I need to detect when the image is touched and if I work with `match_parent` when touch in blank zone the device also detects a touch event.

This an example with "match_parent"

[image]

How could I scale up the image maintaining the aspect ratio?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you try android:layout_width="match_parent"  rather than android:layout_width="wrap_content"  ?

Comment: I've edited the original question with the reason to not use  `match_parent`

Comment: could it be that you have the file t4 with the same resolution in more than one drawable folder? For me your code is working fine

Comment: The t4 resource is only in `res/drawable` folder. I use the same BIG file for all densities and resolutions and scale down or scale up it

Comment: If you are using the same file for all the densities, I can't help you. I have tested your code and works fine. I was testing with a .png image. I guess this does not have nothing to do...